# Error when running a macro from a different excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have two macro enabled Excel files in one directory. One of them being SH.xlsm, which has a macro that should run a macro in my P.xlsm file. Preferably, it should be able to run the code without opening the P.xlsm workbook.

Here is what I currently have in the SH.xlsm file to run the macro called InsertImageTest in P.xlsm.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Call InsertImageTest
    codeWorkBookPath = "C:\Users\AsgeirA\OneDrive\Documents\PowerApps\Signature Signer\"
    codeWorkBookName = "P.xlsm"
    codeWorkBookFullPathName = UCase(Trim(codeWorkBookPath)) & UCase(Trim(codeWorkBookName))
    Debug.Print codeWorkBookFullPathName
    codeWorkbookAlreadyOpen = IsWorkBookOpen(codeWorkBookPath & codeWorkBookName)
    If Not codeWorkbookAlreadyOpen Then
        Workbooks.Open FileName:=codeWorkBookFullPathName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
    End If

    Workbooks("SH.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Data").Activate

    argString = "'" & Trim(codeWorkBookName) & "'!" & Trim("InsertImageTest")
    Application.Run argString
End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

The first minor issue with my code is that it opens the P.xlsm workbook. The second issue is that the "InsertImageTest" macro is not being run. I just opens the second workbook and displays this.

```
Run-time error '1004':

Cannot run the macro "P.xlsm'!InsertImageTest'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some investigation and it looks like the new version of Microsoft (16.0.11727.20188) is causing the problem. I can suggest to downgrade to the older one which will resolve the issue.